# Add +1 (>1) after every time a condition is met

Tags: r, numeric, data-wrangling

(sorry, really don't know how to better phrase this question)

I have a column "have" with 1s and 0s. I want to create a new column "want" where, each time a 1 has occurred, the value of 0 increases to 2, then 3, then 4, etc. 0 should never be 1.

Example:

```
data <- data.frame(have = (c('0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1')), 
                   want = (c('0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '3', '3', '1')))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
data <- data.frame(have = (c('0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1')))  

data$want <- cumsum(as.numeric(data$have)) + 1
data$want[data$want == "1"] <- "0"
data$want[data$have == "1"] <- "1"

data
#>    have want
#> 1     0    0
#> 2     0    0
#> 3     0    0
#> 4     0    0
#> 5     1    1
#> 6     0    2
#> 7     1    1
#> 8     0    3
#> 9     0    3
#> 10    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using the `rle`

```
f <- \(x) {
  rl <- rle(x)
  rl0 <- which(rl$values == 0)
  rl$values[rl0[-1]] <- seq_along(rl$values[rl0[-1]]) + 1
  rep(rl$values, rl$lengths)
}

transform(data, want=f(have))
#    have want
# 1     0    0
# 2     0    0
# 3     0    0
# 4     0    0
# 5     1    1
# 6     0    2
# 7     1    1
# 8     0    3
# 9     0    3
# 10    1    1
```

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf - Running the function gives me an error - Error: unexpected '}' in "}" :-(

Comment: @user303287 Update your R or use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative:

```
transform(data,
          want = pmin(cumsum(have) + cummax(have), 0^-(have != 1)))

   have want
1     0    0
2     0    0
3     0    0
4     0    0
5     1    1
6     0    2
7     1    1
8     0    3
9     0    3
10    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(have = (c('0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1')), 
                   want = (c('0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '3', '3', '1')))


df$want2 <- ifelse(df$have == 1, 1, ifelse(cumsum(df$have) == 0, 0, 1 + cumsum(df$have == 1)))

df
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
transform(
    df,
    want = replace(
        replace(
            cumsum(have == 1) + 1,
            have == 1,
            1
        ),
        seq_along(have) < min(which(have == 1)),
        0
    )
)
```

## Output

```
   have want
1     0    0
2     0    0
3     0    0
4     0    0
5     1    1
6     0    2
7     1    1
8     0    3
9     0    3
10    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works, the only thing is that if there are numerous consecutive 1s in the "have", then it  then "amplifies" the next value (so if two 1s, then the value inerted goes from 1 to 3). This is not a problem for my purpose though, as I am just after a unique id, which it still is. :-)

Comment: @user303287 Good feedback. I guess you can put this info (better with an example) in your post.